# How to display php code and html tags as text in a web page

Tags: php, web

I have the following piece of code and wish to display it as text in a webpage. How can I do it? I wat the code mentioned below to be displayed as text in a webpage. The page might be either a .html page or a .php page. Kindly help.

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Log in!</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  div {
     width:300px;
     height:120px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     margin-top: 100px;
      padding: 30px 20px;
      border:2px solid #00F;
     background-color:#0CF;
     border-radius:10px;
    }

 span{
    margin:0px auto;
     color:#F00;
      font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
     font-size:12px;
  }

 </style>
 </head>

<body>
 </body>
 <?php
 require_once('conn.php');

$sql="select * from contacts where contacts_id=14";
 $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
 $row=$result->fetch_array();
 if( isset($_POST['id']) && $row['email']==$_POST['id'] && $_POST['password']==$row['password'])
 {
     header("location:view.php")    ;
      $_SESSION['sid']= $row['email'];
    $flag=1;
 }
 ?>

 <div>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
 <table align="center" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
      <td>&:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Log In!" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
  </form>
     <?php
      if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $flag==0)
     {
           echo "<center><span>Invalid Id/Password</span></center>";    
      }

   ?>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: If your PHP parser is parsing your PHP tags in your HTML page then replace the < character with &lt;.  As far as showing code in HTML you can try putting it inside <code>..</code>

Comment: You can give the file a `.phps` extension, or use `highlight_file()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php - If that'swhat this question is about. Or, are you asking to do a "printer-friendly" method? *Your question is a bit unclear.*

Comment: Thanks Fred for your reply. I am not looking for a printerfriendly version. I only want the code to be displayed as it is on a web page.

Comment: You're welcome. You can try either method I posted in my comment above. To call me out directly in order for me to get a notification, add the `@` symbol followed by my name, should you need more info.

Comment: @DebashisSikdar I have posted an answer for you below.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [highlight_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)
 function

```
 <?php

 highlight_string("YOUR STRING/CODE GOES HERE");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$gen_query_data= htmlspecialchars(' $'.$db_val_clean.'_ser = $_POST["'.$sel_name_clean.'_ser"];')."<br>";

     echo $gen_query_data;
```

please change your variables

Answer (score 0):

if your server isn't set up to process .html for the php tag, you're fine to do exactly what you've done.

You can also use this:  `&lt;?php`   which would render as `<?php` but not be seen by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can use is PHP's `highlight_file()` function:

```
<?php
highlight_file("your_file.php");
?>
```

You can also use `.html` file extensions `highlight_file("your_file.html")`.

Even a `.txt` file extension `highlight_file("your_file.txt")`.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard Afternoon *Sam!*

Answer (score -1):

this question is pretty old , but as long as no one used this solution so this would be helpful .

using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) :

> htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities

```
echo htmlspecialchars("your special character goes here");
```